# How to write a formula field condition in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, formula

I need to create a formula field with below logic:

```
If Test_Org__r.Name = ABC then it should display Alpha

Else
If Test_Org__r.Name = PQR then it should display Beta

Else
If Test_Org__r.Name =  STV then it should display Gamma

Else 
If Test_Org__r.Name = XYZ then it should display Delta

Else display N/A
```

How can I achieve this?